# Windows Server 2012 EventViewer Powershell Script error

Tags: windows, powershell

I am having a bit of a strange error, seems like it's permissions related, though I have done a fair amount of searching and none of the suggestions have worked.

I have a powershell script, running directly on an Windows2012 DC.  It attempts to get information from the EventViewer logs, specifically "Security", but all of a sudden the server is now (as of a few days ago) saying that "Get-EventLog:  Requested access is not allowed".

It's a very simple command as well:

```
Get-Eventlog -Logname Security -Newest 1
```

But the result is the following:

```
Get-EventLog : Requested registry access is not allowed.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-EventLog -Newest 1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.SecurityException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
```

What I have attempted:

- Gave myself permission (made sure admins/server operators have full
  access), also added "Everyone" temporarily.  This was done in
  RegEdit:
  ***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog***
- Cleared Logs for Security in EventViewer
- Attempted to run same script with same permissions on secondary DC,
  and it works there.  Also works if I specify -Computername
  SecondDC.mydomain.ads, but not if I don't specify it or specify
  FirstDc.mydomain.ads.

I have a feeling something could be corrupt?  I have no idea where to look at this point.  I should be able to pull Event Logs from powershell as an admin.

Comment: Use `Get-Eventlog -Logname Security -Newest 1` from powershell elevated (_run as administrator_).

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clear I ran things in elevated mode, as admin.

Comment: Did you run it as admin user, or did you run it with Right click -> "Run as administrator"? Even if your user is admin, a powershell does not automaticaly open with elevated rights.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a workaround, its too complicated for a simple and obvious security monitoring request but it works on w2012:

- as an admin run regedit
- nav to KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog
- right click on 'Security'
- click Permissions
- add a group (like 'Event Log Readers')
- select the group you added
- check Read under Allow
- exit regedit and add this group to users who need access
- these users will need to log out and back in to activate

Yes others have found this before me http://powerkb.se/?p=614

Comment: I have the same issue, I have set the permission like you have commented above. But it's still not working :(. Do you have any ideas ?