# Requested registry access is not allowed - server logs

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

I am trying to run a script to gather the application, system and security log errors. I can run it remotely but I have to go over the WAN to do that. I want to run it locally on the domain controller. When I run it locally, I get "Requested registry access is not allowed". I have already done everything that is recommended online to fix this, including giving the rights to the Event Log Readers group in the registry, as described here: [Windows Server 2012 EventViewer Powershell Script error](https://serverfault.com/questions/765472/windows-server-2012-eventviewer-powershell-script-error)
So I am stumped because it is still not working. I don't know what else to try. I can't find any other fixes online. The server is running Windows Server 2012R2.

Comment: I would use procmon to find the access denies

Answer (score 1):

Well, this may seem a bit obvious but you didn't state it so I'm going to ask anyway: have you disabled UAC on this domain controller? Not only the slider control but also the [registry setting](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13953.windows-server-2012-deactivating-uac.aspx)?

Microsoft actually ["recommends" disabling UAC on servers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2526083/disabling-user-account-control-uac-on-windows-server), as long as only admins logon and they only perform admin functions (i.e. no end users and no desktop functions)

Comment: +1 because that's a great article, but it's for "well managed systems" that don't run "risky" applications. My litmus test is if I can browse the internet UAC stays on